# Passing a path to the MVC4 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

One of the parameters the client needs to pass to the server is a file path e.g. `path/to/data`.

Obviously I cant just sent it as it is as the MVC4 controller uses forward slashes to separate its parameters. I though I would be safe url escaping the file path - eg. `path%2Fto%2Fdata`, transmitting it to the server, and then unescaping it on the server.

But this doesn't work - MVC4 doesn't recognise the route. Does MVC4 unescape the %2f or something?

UPDATE

From the response in the browser it seems like MVC4 is unescaping the filepath before it inspects it to get at the various fields in the URL.

If I then do a double escape, it reports...

```
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence
```

After a bit or reading I tried the suggestion to add to web.config in the  part...

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```

But then it reports...

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).
```

Comment: How are you doing this? Give us some code!

Comment: @Fals, what parts of the code do you want? There is quite a lot. The client is in python. I dont thik this is relevant as I can see that it has url encoded the path. Or do you want the route config?

Comment: Did you use a * in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wildcard

```
 routes.MapRoute("Path",
           "{*path}",
           new { 
                  controller = "Content", 
                  action = "Index", 
                  path = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
```

Or in a url-encoded querystring parameter

Comment: Thanks, Are you saying that `path%2Fto%2Fdata` aught to work? (i.e. maybe its some other bug)

Comment: Do you have a parameter "string path" in the controller and no routes above that one that matches before it? Try setting a breakpoint there in controller and see if it reaches there

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If I send for example `path_to_data` it works fine

Comment: Wait, just understood what you meant by the query string answer (it was bit brief for me). I didnt realise that you don't need to compose the http request as a slash separated string but can just go.. `?filepath=path/to/data/` This is a simpler solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like MVC4 is decoding the filepath before it inspects it to get at the various fields in the URL. SO you need to dbl encode it. Also...

In Web.config add/replace ..

.. in the system.web part

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

... and in the system.webserver part add...

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```